# Load clang pass from within another pass

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I have two LLVM passes, one which requires the outputs of the other. So in PassB I have:

```
void DiscoPoP::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &Info) const{
    Info.addRequired<PassA>();
}
```

I tried adding the snippet below to PassB, but when running `clang -Xclang -load -Xclang LLVMPassB.so` I get an error: undefined symbol: _ZN18PassA2IDE

```
static RegisterStandardPasses PassLoader(
    PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
    [](const PassManagerBuilder &Builder,
       legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) { PM.add(new PassA()); });
```

If I load PassA in clang as well, it works: `clang -Xclang -load -Xclang LLVMPassA.so -Xclang -load -Xclang LLVMPassB.so`

But it seems redundant to have to load it manually if  it required from the PassB. Is there a way to load PassA programmatically from PassB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get an error: undefined symbol: _ZN18PassA2IDE

Because the PassA isn't visible to clang.

> If I load PassA in clang as well, it works: clang -Xclang -load -Xclang LLVMPassA.so -Xclang -load -Xclang LLVMPassB.so

As expected.

> But it seems redundant to have to load it manually if it required from the PassB.

Only if there was a way for clang know know about `PassA` when passB is supplied as flag. clang has no way of knowing where `LLVMPassA.so` resides unless we pass as flag.

> Is there a way to load PassA programmatically from PassB?

This can be done if you modify the LLVM source code and put both your passes there. Registering a pass within LLVM pass manager is straightforward. See https://reviews.llvm.org/D50658 (Hot cold splitting pass) as an example, specifically changes in `lib/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.cpp`, and function `createHotColdSplittingPass`.